# iOS ARC:What's the principle of xcode compiler to add retain and release to code under arc?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, release, retain

From iOS 5,Apple introduced ARC to replace MRC.When use MRC,the coder add retain and release for memory control.After use ARC the compiler will add retain and release for you.What's the principle of compiler to add retain and release for code?
You can paste some link or write someting you want.Thank you!!!

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where retains and released are added are specified in the [ARC specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), although it's kind of a technical read.